# Renaming messages but it shows "Operation not permitted" on linux system

Tags: linux

I'm using Centos 8.0 and my kernel version:
4.18.0-147.5.1.x86_64

**Backgroud**:
The messages on my host not rotated for a long time,and when I use "logrotate -v -f" to force rotating messages, it shows "rename messages: Operation not permitted".So I try renaming the messages immediately.

```
-rw-------    1 root    15464299992 Jul 15 10:12 messages
-rw-------    1 root       11644353 Sep  7  2020 messages-20200907.gz
-rw-------    1 root        8834073 Sep 13  2020 messages-20200913.gz
```

```
renaming /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20210715
error: failed to rename /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages-20210715: Operation not permitted
```

Here is my operation and the terminal's output:

```
[root@node-5 log]# mv messages messages-20210715
mv: cannot move ‘messages’ to ‘messages-20210715’: Operation not permitted
[root@node-5 ~]# whoami
root
```

I also used `strace` to follow, and the result was as below:

```
stat("messages2", 0x7fff6c37aae0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("messages", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=15464637645, ...}) = 0
lstat("messages2", 0x7fff6c37a790)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "messages", AT_FDCWD, "messages2", 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I logined as root,why did I still come across such problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: has `messages` been made immutable?  check with `lsattr messages`, and look for an `i` in the attributes.  it would look something like `----i----------------- ./messages`.   if it has been made immutable, you can undo that using `chattr` (which has to be run as root).  e.g. `sudo chattr -i messages`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems messages was truly chattred with 'a' so it can't be renamed.

Comment: cool, great to hear it's solved.  please write it up as an answer (with a summary of the problem and what you did to fix it) and i'll give it up an upvote if it's good.  you can accept your own answer after 24 hours or so, i think.

Comment: And keep in mind that if this file has been chattred to 'a', it's probably for a good reason.
Think twice before removing this attr and renaming it.

Comment: it's hard to imagine there's any good reason to prevent a log file from being rotated.   and if it needs to be append-only for some reason (security, perhaps - but if security is that important, the log should be sent to a remote loghost), the `logrotate` configuration needs to be modified to remove the append-only attribute with `chattr -a`, rotate the log file, and then add the attribute back (to **both** the original file and the new one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the problem was solved, appreciate @cas 's solution.Here is why and how:

1.Use `lsattr /var/log` and it shows messages has a file attribute 'a':

```
---------------- ./spooler-20200913.gz
---------------- ./maillog-20201004
-----a---------- ./messages
---------------- ./escl-upgrade.log
```

2.File attribute 'a' means "append only", the file with 'a' can only be wrote and can't be renamed or moved.

3.Use `chattr -a messages` to disable the 'a' attribute, then messages can be logrotated again.